# Matplotlib animation error assert self._cachedRenderer is not None

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am currently trying to animate a simple harmonic motion system. It plots a graph of acceleration, displacement and velocity graphs which uses the code:

```
self.fig = plt.Figure()
self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=master)
self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(in_=master, column=0,row=1)
self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
self.line, = self.ax.plot(self.x, self.y)
self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, interval=0, blit=True)
self.root.mainloop()
```

This is within a tkinter framework. self.x and self.y are just the different sets of data that are required to display the three different graphs. Once the data is calculated it initally displays a displacement graph by defualt. The user can then press an acceleration or velocity button to swap to a different graph in the same place.

The first graph displays fine but then once the user clicks on one of the other buttons to show a different graph an error of:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 534, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 141, in _on_timer
    TimerBase._on_timer(self)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1203, in _on_timer
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 877, in _step
    still_going = Animation._step(self, *args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 736, in _step
    self._draw_next_frame(framedata, self._blit)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 756, in _draw_next_frame
    self._post_draw(framedata, blit)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 779, in _post_draw
    self._blit_draw(self._drawn_artists, self._blit_cache)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 794, in _blit_draw
    a.axes.draw_artist(a)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 2099, in draw_artist
    assert self._cachedRenderer is not None
AssertionError
```

comes up and stops the programme from working correctly. What can I do differently to stop this error?

Comment: PS. At no point do I declare when the graphing should stop, say after 500 frames and appears to continually plot.. Is that critical?

Comment: Can you post the code (or a simplified version of it) that implements "the other buttons to show a different graph"? My guess is you just need to re-initialize the animation.  The error is because the plot hasn't been drawn yet (and therefore the renderer doesn't exist), and the animation is trying to blit ontop of something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

@Joe Kington, So for an acceleration graph I would use the button code as:

```
self.accelerationbutton = ttk.Button(self.Buttonframe, text="Acceleration-time", command=self.acceleration)
```

and for that function it would be:

```
    def acceleration(self, x, y):
        self.fig = plt.Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=master)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(in_=master, column=0,row=1)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(x, y)
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, interval=0, blit=True)
        self.root.mainloop()
```

The code I use to draw the graph for each different graph is identical apart from the data being drawn, is that the issue?